# I don't know why axios return full html code. I can't get the intended data with laravel + vue. Please tell me the cause

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I created simple api functionality with laravel + vue(axios).

But It doesn't work as I planned.

The below is my code.

```
// RecipeController.php
class RecipeController extends Controller
{
    public function abc()
    {
        $banana = 'banana';
        Log::debug('banana');
        return $apple;
    }
}
```

```
// component.vue
const abc = () => {
    return axios.get('/api/abc')
}

onMounted(async () => {
    const res3 = await abc()
    console.log(res3.data) // please refer to the below image
})
```

```
// api.php

Route::get('/abc', [RecipeController::class, 'abc']);
```

```
// route.php
Route::get('{any?}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

[image]

I want screen to display 'banana', but it won't.

Log::debug also don't work.

Please tell me the cause of this phenomenon.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: seems like your `routes.php` has covered the `api.php` by something like `Route::get('/{any}')` since you are writing a Vue SPA

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I understand the cause.
And How can I output 'banana' in developer tool console?

Comment: According to your descriptions, the `abc()` has never been running, so the issue may probably caused by routes. Check your `RouteServiceProvider.php` first, and see if the `api.php` has been registered correctly. Then, you may add an `AcceptHeader` middleware for your `api.php`

Comment: You must register the `api.php` before `web.php` in `RouteServiceProvider.php` or the `api.php` may be covered by `web.php`.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
 I completely forgot to tell you that other axios.get return my desired result.
So I assume that RouteServiceProvider.php have nothing to do with this problem.